# Is it better practice to restart threads in an app, or have the server restart the whole application?

Tags: python, multithreading, server, cron, cloud

I have a python app that tracks busses in my city for certain data using their arrivals api. I have a limited amount of calls I can make and I don't want to overload them anyways, so I am currently running 30 threads to track data on certain bus stops every day. Each thread randomly selects a bus stop, and continually tracks data for busses that arrive to that stop.

The idea is that I want to have at least a day's worth of data on every bus stop eventually, but I think going in order of the bus stops might lead to problems with getting data from the same drivers. My solution is that every time I start a thread, I randomly select a bus stop from the full list of bus stops, and then put it in another list of ones I've already tracked (it keeps randomly selecting until it gets one that hasn't been tracked yet). When the list is the same length as the full list, it clears (meaning there has now been a day's worth of data tracked from every stop) and we repeat the cycle until it gets full again, etc.

**tldr here's the part I'm wondering about:**  I want to stop my current running threads, and get new threads at 2:00 AM every night. If I want to achieve this, would it be better practice to write something in my app that does this, or to do a cron job or something to just restart the app on the server at 2:00 AM every night?

Here's the code for reference:

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":

    numstops = 30
    stops_to_track = make_stop_list(numstops)

    for stop in stops_to_track:
        _thread.start_new_thread(track_data, (stop,))
        time.sleep(10)

    while True:
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, nevermind. I did some research and it seems like it would be better just to change the parameters at 2 AM.